# Print output de CRON no terminal - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Criei um CRON no Laravel e queria printar uma informação no terminal onde o comando está sendo executado (terminal do Ubuntu, nesse caso).

Qual é o comando pra isso no Laravel?

Exemplo:

```
public function handle()
{
    $digitalCertificates = DB::table('digital_certificates')->get();

    $today = new \DateTime();

    foreach($digitalCertificates as $digitalCertificate) {

        $expirationDate = $digitalCertificate->expirationDate;
        $interval = $today->diff($expirationDate)->days;

        print($interval); //EXEMPLO. Informação a ser printada no terminal

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O próprio "echo" resolve a sua duvida.